# RiotJS: mount multiple tags getting isntance on page start don't work

Tags: riot.js

When I have two tag's and I'm trying to get both instance using [0] on mount method, only first works. This problem appear when I need start the page mounting more than one tag passing date on mount and getting they instance.
OBS: I really need the tag intance, I checked and the problem appear becouse mount method is returning a undefined, and I cant acess [0] of a undefined type. But when I try to use this code to get a instance like that:

```
riot.compile(function()
{
var tag = riot.mount(tagSelector,
{
data: data
})[0];
tags[tagSelector] = tag;
});
```

The same problem happen.

Can you reproduce the issue?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wpa8it73Um33bg536wTS

On which browser/OS does the issue appear?

IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Which version of Riot does it affect?

Riot v3.3.1